# How does an OS with a 1 kHz tick rate make nanosecond measurements?

Tags: operating-system, cpu, timing

I've worked on low level devices such as microcontrollers, and I understand how timers and interrupts work; but, I was wondering how an operating system with a 1 kHz tick rate is able to give time measurements of events down to the nanosecond precision. Are they using timers with input capture or something like that? Is there a limit to how many measurements you can take at once?

Comment: It depends on the platform, so what are we talking about here?

Comment: @harold Let's say Intel x86 for example. If it is very varied by platforms, then an explanation of any will do.

Answer (score 0):

On modern x86 platforms, the [TSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) can be used for high resolution time measurement, and even to generate high resolution interrupts (that's a different interface of course, but it counts in TSC ticks). There is no inherent limit to the number of parallel measurements. Before the "Invariant TSC" feature was introduced it was much harder to use the TSC that way, because the TSC frequency changed with the C-state (and so usually went out of sync across cores and in any case was hard to use as a stopwatch).